# Problemas con Android Canary 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Descargue hace varios dias Android Studio Canary 4.1, pero no importa que actualice todo, que haga un nuevo proyecto, me arroja este error.

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\estevita\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling9.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'test5' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'test5' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.getProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:130)
    at sync_studio_tooling9_29swhphv0bi7ya2flieof91as$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\Users\estevita\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling9.gradle:7)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions.with(Actions.java:251)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$2$1.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:79)
    at ...
```

Lo he intentado todo, Gradle online, Gradle offline, Actualizar SDK, Nuevo proyecto, viejos proyectos y ninguno funciona. Alguna idea? Uso Win7 32bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal es que la Android Studio versión 4.1 en todas sus versiones Canary (Actualmente 6 hasta el 17 de abril de 2020), solamente puede funcionar en un sistema operativo de 64 bits!

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Si instalaras  Android Studio versión 4.1 en un sistema operativo de 64 bitss y tratas de actualizar un proyecto, es importante que elimines el directorio `.gradle` de tu proyecto para que este se vuelva a generar con la nueva configuración.